# How to remove rows in r where all columns value are the exact same

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates

I have a large dataframe in R that consists of 13 columns and 16407 rows.
I would like to remove rows from the dataframe that have the same exact values in all 13 columns not just some of them.

I have extracted the duplicated row into a dataframe to a csv file and have noticed that there are still unique values.

My dataframe has the following column names

```
names(goal_stats) <- c("date", "campaign", "audience", "creative_family", "creative_version", 
                     "platform", "ad_format", "goal", "completions", 
                     "campaign_traffic", "days_from_max_date", "latest_report")
```

I have tried the following code but this only returns rows where some of the columns are duplicated not all 12, there are still unique values remaining.

```
# New dataframe to explore duplicate, counted  values, to explore any possible patterns

goal_duplicates <- goal_stats %>%
  add_count(date, campaign, audience, creative_family, creative_version, platform, ad_format, 
            goal, completions, campaign_traffic, days_from_max_date, latest_report)%>%
  filter(n>1) %>%
  distinct()


write_csv(goal_duplicates, "goal_duplicates.csv")

#Remove duplicate
goal_stats1 <- goal_stats %>%
  distinct(.keep_all = TRUE)
```

For example the new dataframe will return rows with the same values across 11 out of the 12 columns.  But for completions each row has a different value one row will have 6 completions whereas another will have 9 completions.  Therefore, the rows are not exactly the same as they contain a different values for completions.

Sorry for my formatting I'm still a beginner.

Comment: Hi Alexander, Can you add an example to your question? From my experience, distinct() works fine

Comment: What is the relationship between `goal_duplicates` and `goal_stats1`?  It would be really helpful if you can provide a small reproducible example and expected output from that example.  Even if it just toy data, like `df <- tibble(a = c(1, 1, 1, 2), b = c(3, 3, 3, 4), c = c(5, 5, 5, 6))`, that represents your problem - it is much easier to help you that way.

Comment: If your cols are all numeric, this should work in most cases: `df[rowSums(df)/ncol(df) != df[,1], ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% filter_all(any_vars(duplicated(.)))
```